# How to Update All Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In example I want to Update All Columns in a table by One Value

If there is Table Consists of Three Columns I want to Update All Columns by One Value Like this

> id   Mark1  Mark 2 
>     001  NA     NA

I Want to Update NA to Mark1 and 2 at once in One SQL Query

**But Should Not Be Like this**

```
"Update stu set Mark1=NA Mark2=NA where id = 001";
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What you have is generally how it should be done. You may have to write some dynamic SQL to accomplish it otherwise.

Comment: why? ***But Should Not Be Like this***

Comment: OP may be looking for something like `set (* but id)='NA' where id=1`, which is not defined yet in any SQL.

Comment: Just curious, why avoid the "set Mark1=NA Mark2=NA" method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want the way you want to do it.

The half solutions you can consider are :

- Set the default value when you create your table, but once it's updated you can't reset it again.
- Do it in multiple steps by querying metadata tables and constructing your query dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think that "There's no way..." and the accepted answer is misleading! I would say there's an options, depending of situation. (that's why I don't like stackoverflow, too much 'good' accepted answers). Google shows in top results link to this post for a question: "update all colums mysql". And look what's here...

I just right now was needed to do the same (to update all colums at once in one query without using `column_name=value`). And here I'm and it gives me nothing. So, I just figured out and I think this may be useful for some folks!

Let's just take the code of this question creator (@Code_Tesh). So, to do the trick we can combine query `DELETE` and `INSERT INTO` like this:

```
"DELETE FROM stu WHERE id = 001; INSERT INTO stu VALUES('001', 'NA', 'NA')";
```

**That's it!** ⚠⚠⚠ P.S. Yes, this is not exactly one query, and for someone, maybe, this is not very convenient, but it's a solution for some cases. I have no idea what backend is using OP... and if he does that at all, but for PHP for example a piece of code might look like this:

```
$mysqli->multi_query(
    "DELETE FROM `stu` WHERE `id` = 001; INSERT INTO `stu` VALUES('001', 'NA', 'NA')"
);
```

**I mean, when someone saying to you "There's no way...", just don't give up so ease ;)**